# Get 24h activity from mysql (time tracking)

Tags: php, mysql, charts, time-tracking

We have to track the time some users (employees) are spending on our Website (Backend Tool, they are logged in).

Currently we are saving an info into a MySQL Table every 5 minutes (based on activity (page open) or showing/reading a page (through an ajax updater, fired every 5 minutes).

In MySQL we store the user ID and a MySQL timestamp.

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |      timestamp      |
+----+---------------------+
| 28 | 2016-11-25 15:51:25 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 15:55:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 16:00:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 16:05:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 16:10:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 16:15:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 16:55:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:00:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:05:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:10:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:15:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:20:00 |
| 28 | 2016-11-25 17:25:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

**What would be your suggestion to retrieve an "activity protocol" for a given user in a given time period.**

i.e. "show all times" where a user has been active yesterday, last week, last month"

The result for Nov. 25th for user 28 should give an result like:

```
2016-11-25 -> 49 minutes
15:51-16:15 (24 min) 
17:00-17:25 (25 min)
```

Selecting those times from the DB is not the problem, but how can we combine those to an intelligent format...

yesterday: 8 hours 15 minutes,
lastweek:  52 hours 35 minutes,
last month: 175 hours 45 minutes

Also a "hint" on how to get a nice graphical representation would be very helpful:

[image: Weelky "hour" report]

Comment: Of course I am also open for any other approach - goal is to see how long the users really work on the site. Needs to be fully browser integrated and no plugin etc....

Comment: What about using Google analytics with custom logging?

Comment: Ok but if a user logout in the middle of the day, then come back. What rule should you use then?

Comment: @chris85
this will not work everywhere (china) and also the reporting will not be possible from within our tools (in association to the given user id's)...

Comment: @FelippeDuarte If user log's out, we will not have any entries into the timetable for this user.

Comment: If user works from 15h~17h, then logout, then come back again at 18h~21h, it's like he/she didn't work that day?

Comment: The userid would be accessible if you sent it with the **custom** logging. Why is Google analytics not working in China?

Comment: @chris85 ALL Google services are beein blocked in china :(
No Google fonts, no Codes from Google, no analytics ... Thanks to the Great China Firewall

Comment: @FelippeDuarte In your case (15-17 & 18-21) we would say the user worked 5 hours

Comment: I think that is specific for you. I can see the google analytics loading in china for my site and have traffic from China in our analytics.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to divide the time list into ranges. Each range will represent the period of time during which the user was active. Next we need to find the time span for each range. The time span can be calculated by finding the difference between the highest and lowest times in a range. We can then add the time spans for all the ranges. This will give the amount of time the user was active.